# v-model is not updating value in real time for a specific field. Other fields with same datatype are working fine. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a specific model in which there are multiple values that can be updated through form given on the webpage. The values are like "Quantity", "Rate", "Amount", "Net rate", etc.

The issue is, I am binding those values with my inputs using `v-model` and it is working perfectly perfect for all the fields except the "net rate" field! It s not updating value in real time but when I update some value in field and click refresh on Vue-devtools UI, it gets updated! It's just not being updated as soon as the value changes in the field. And that too, For a specific field called "net_rate"!

I have no Idea what's going on here! Here is my code, The first field with id `discount_perc` is working perfectly! When I update anything in this field, it gets updated as soon as I edit value in the field. But same is not happening with the `net_rate` field.

```
<div class="inline-form-group col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1 text-right">
    <label for="discount_perc" style="color:teal;font-size:14px;">Dis %</label>
    <input type="text" ref="discount_perc" @keydown.enter="$refs.net_rate.focus()" @input="setAmount()" v-model="selectedItem.discount_perc" class="form-control text-right" />
</div>
<div class="inline-form-group col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1 text-right">
    <label for="net_rate" style="color:teal;font-size:14px;">Net rate</label>
    <input type="text" ref="net_rate" v-model="selectedItem.net_rate" @input="updateAmount()" @keydown.enter="addItem()" @keydown.tab="addItem()" class="form-control text-right" />
</div>
```

Here are my methods that I am firing on input event for both of these fields.

```
setAmount: function () {
    var discount_percAmount = this.selectedItem.discount_perc?(this.selectedItem.discount_perc*this.selectedItem.price)/100:0;
    this.selectedItem.net_rate = this.selectedItem.price-discount_percAmount;

    if(this.selectedItem.size_breadth > 0 && this.selectedItem.size_length > 0){
        this.selectedItem.item_amt = this.selectedItem.net_rate*this.selectedItem.quantity*this.selectedItem.size_breadth*this.selectedItem.size_length;
    } else {
        this.selectedItem.item_amt = this.selectedItem.net_rate*this.selectedItem.quantity;
    }
},
updateAmount: function () {
    if(this.selectedItem.size_breadth > 0 && this.selectedItem.size_length > 0){
        this.selectedItem.item_amt = parseFloat(this.selectedItem.net_rate)*this.selectedItem.quantity*this.selectedItem.size_breadth*this.selectedItem.size_length;
    } else {
        this.selectedItem.item_amt = parseFloat(this.selectedItem.net_rate)*this.selectedItem.quantity;
    }
},
```

> I know there is one redundant piece of code that can be converted into a method, I will deal with it later, right now, My priority is to get this thing working.

I tried alerting `net_rate` value calculation in `updateAmount()` function and it works. But it's not updating the value in model. It requires refresh! I am scratching my head since more than 24 hours but can't solve the issue.

Has anyone faced the same issue before? Please let me know the reason and possible solution! Any kind of help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE:** Here is my Data.

```
data () {
    return {
        availableParties:[],
        party: [],
        availableArchitechs: [],
        availableStaff: [],
        availableLocations: [],
        location: '',
        availableItemCodes: [],
        selectedItem: [],
        quotation: {
            party_id: null, date:new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0], architech: '',staff: '', items: [], order_no: '',
            item_amt: 0,gst_0_amt:0,gst_5_amt:0,gst_12_amt:0,gst_18_amt:0,gst_28_amt:0,final_amt:0
        },
        latestQuotation: [],
        partySpecificItemInfo:{
            rate: 0,
            discount_perc: 0,
            net_rate: 0
        },
        updateAllowed: true,
        selectedItemImageExist: false,
    }
},
```

Comment: Show me your data() method

Comment: Updated my question @Borjante

Comment: try to set data.selectedItem as an object and define the initial values as null

Comment: And set values individually that I get from my API endpoint?

Comment: If you use ES6, you can use the Object spread operator to make it a one-liner

Comment: But first let's just focus on solving the first problem, which is the reactivity of your v-model

Answer (score 10):

The problem here is that you've got an Array initialized in VueJS in your data property which **is observable**. But then you replace it with an Object in your function, and that Object is not observable. You can do some work to make that observable, too, or just start with an Object by default so it's already observable, then use `Vue.set` to add properties that become observable to that object.

Make it an object by default:

```
selectedItem: {},
```

Use `Vue.set` when you want to work on that object:

```
Vue.set(this.selectedItem, 'property', value)
```

Just replace `property` with things like `net_rate` and `value` with whatever should be the value of that property in the object.

Now it will be reactive and will have the observer attached to it so the value will correctly update.

[Docs on Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)

Note this line from the docs here:

> Vue cannot detect normal property additions (e.g. this.myObject.newProperty = 'hi')

Comment: I wanted to put it a little more laymen, Adding properties to an object are not tracked, if you want to use it this way: [ this.myObject.prop = 'hi' ] then the object must have the  property in at the created cycle. so putting something in such as [ if (typeof this.myObject.prop === 'undefined') { this.myObject.prop = ''; } ] in the created() function would allow you to v-model like you normally do.

Comment: Thank you @Ohgodwhy, I didn`t know about Vue.set() and it definately helped me!